# Replace text in current tag using inline js

Tags: jquery

is it possible to replace a string in the current tag using jquery like this:

```
<td class="price"><script>$(this).text(accounting.formatMoney(parseFloat({{ product.price }}).toFixed(2), "€ ", 2, ".", ","));</script></td>
```

actually this doesn't work.

thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could set it up in a function to do, but not until after the page loads... something like this is what you're looking for... First, change your HTML:

```
<td class="price">{{ product.price }}</td>
```

Then this script should work for you:

```
$(function(){
    $('.price').each(function(){
        var price = $(this).text()
        $(this).text(accounting.formatMoney(parseFloat(price).toFixed(2), "€ ", 2, ".", ","))
    });
});
```